# How to visually represent a color contrast issue to a person with normal color vision?

Tags: color, contrast, accessibility

I have two colors — #FFFFFF and #009688.

I want to simulate graphically how it will appear to a person with color blindness issues so that I can present it to a person with normal vision and explain it.

Is there any accurate way to do this?

Comment: Both Adobe Illustrator and Adobe Photoshop can display an image as seen by protanopia and deuteranopia color blind people. (FYI, they both see that color as 'dark grey', so there seems no problem with *contrast*.)

Comment: There are lots of good resources for this. I'd take a look at [this list on our UX sister site](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/71/13050) and also at the other 'duplicate' question it links to. There may be better, newer resources too.

Answer (score 1):

There is not just 1 type of colour blindness, but several ones.

I would prepare a sample image and use http://www.color-blindness.com/coblis-color-blindness-simulator/

[image: Normal vision]

And it gives you for example this result,

[image: Colour blind example]

But you should take a look into thoose kind of simulators, and prepare a more interesting test.

This particular set of colours have no "contrast" issue in general terms. But there are different kinds of contrast, hue contrast, shade contrast or saturation contrast. So probably you need to be more specific regarding this test.